# Need help to write a bash script to move files from one server to another server

Tags: bash, shell

I need help writing a `bash` shell script to move files from one directory to another directory in different servers then delete the files from the original servers I moved the files.

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash 
mv /successfactors/fotos /successfactors/fotos_resp
mv /successfactors/fotos /fotos 
ssh user@server 'rm /successfactors/fotos'
```

Comment: I type this but not sure if it will work:                       <!-- language: ... -->                                                                                #!/bin/bash
mv /successfactors/fotos /successfactors/fotos_resp
mv /successfactors/fotos /fotos
ssh user@server 'rm /successfactors/fotos'

Comment: check out rsync command... you don't even need a full script, just a single line of proper rsync command. Google for how to use rsync and some examples. rsync also can delete the source files after copying.

Comment: thank you for your help i appreciate it i will try to find out that command

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have files on Server1 that you want to move to Server2, then delete the original files from Server1. Is it correct?

Comment: yes correct Thorium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rsync` for this:

On **Server1**:

```
rsync --progress -avz -e ssh /successfactors/fotos username@server2:/successfactors/fotos_resp
rm -f /successfactors/fotos
```

Comment: ty very much Thorium i will try this